# How to increment variable by reference?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

How to increment variable by reference instead:

```
 let sum = 0;
    this.rows.forEach(model => {
      sum += model.hours;
    });
    return sum;
```

I need to do something this:

```
this.rows.forEach(model => {
   let &sum += model.hours;
});
```

Comment: What about the first section isnt working correctly? Would [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't... at least not directly. Primitives are always passed by value in JavaScript.

If you need to do something like this, you can however wrap it up in an object (which are passed by reference).

```js
const a = () => {
  const sum = { value: 0 };
  b(sum);
  console.log(sum.value);
};

const b = (sum) => {
  sum.value += 100;
};

a();
```

Wrapping up a primitive in an object will let you update it by reference. You'd then just have to read the primitive back out of the value.

**Important note:** if you destructure the value out of the object *it will lose it's by-reference-ness* and just act like a primitive again.

```js
const a = () => {
  const sum = { value: 0 };
  b(sum);
  console.log(sum.value);
};

const b = ({ value }) => {
  value += 100;
};

a();
```

Comment: Or I can pass this parameter to function like: `function a(&sum) {}` Right?

Comment: Unless there is a new ES201X syntax I'm unfamiliar with and can't find with Google, I don't think that is a thing. JavaScript doesn't really do pointer/reference like languages like C++ do.